# Origin of "big green button"?

Tags: buttons, color, size

I found meme about **big green button**.

When people visit download sites (like software directories, file hosting sites, torrents, etc) after completing reading page title and deciding to download they look for *big green button*...

I have interest to know origin of color and size choice.

I found this sources:

- "When User Hits Machine" is Xerox film from 1983, more info at http://www.workpractice.com/wpt-fest/introduction.html and at http://athinkingperson.com/2010/06/02/where-the-big-green-copier-button-came-from/
- http://biggreenbutton.net/ (humor site about this button from 1996)

Also possibly related links:

- [On mobile phones why is the green (call) button at the left and red (hang) button at the right side?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15430/on-mobile-phones-why-is-the-green-call-button-at-the-left-and-red-hang-butto)
- [Red buttons in an e-commerce site?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/red-buttons-in-an-e-commerce-site/)

**UPDATE**. Interesting color marking agreements can be found at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage

Answer (score 4):

The green and red colors are traditionally used in the engineering as "positive, allowed, safe, yes" (green) and "negative, forbidden, danger, no" (red) indication.

This tradition is very old and widespread and all people are taught to perceive these colors in this way.

So, it would be very unwise to use these colors in other meaning, because this will cause the user got confused.

Comment: In Japan, red would be considered "positive, allowed, safe, yes". Generalization can be dangerous.

Comment: So, in Japan the traffic lights are red for "OK to pass"? Good to know. :P Maybe it was true in 15-th century, but not now and not here.

Comment: @BartGijssens that applies to the perception of red as a general colour, but not when used as an indicator.  The same applies to most of East Asia.

Comment: In Japan, like in most other countries, there is a traffic law that explains the meaning of the traffic lights and the required behaviour of people using the public roads. That does not take away that it is a generalization to state that all people are taught to perceive red as negative, forbidden, danger, no. There are variations depending on context and culture.

Comment: @JohnGB: do you have some source for this? Japanese people have always warned me not to simply use red as an indicator for warnings, errors as it can be interpreted as positive, or as offensive.

Comment: @BartGijssens these are different things IMO. For example I like red cars and the red color in generally and don't think the red cars are dangerous or forbidden. But we are talking about engineering and ergonomics here - where red indicators and red buttons always have negative meaning. Regardless of the culture.

Comment: @johnfound late comment but: in many Asian countries red and green have different _meanings_. For example red in stock trade mean "up" and green means "down". Also red means happiness and it's a _positive_ color. Red light in semaphores (to take your example) is just for coherence with countries from where they _imported_ cars (like left side driving in Japan or left-to-right direction when writing in horizontal).  They _learned_ it's like that. It's so widely accepted that sometimes (not always) you may ignore this _issue_ (unless you specifically target only their market)...

Comment: ...but you should carefully consider every implication when dealing with dangerous/critical devices/UIs or when _feeling_ is involved. Usually industrial stack lights follow _western_ convention (red = alert) but exceptions exist (for example I saw temperature indicators where red means _low_...sigh). You should check each specific scenario and do not generalize. My wife is Asian and after years I still find culture-related differences.

Answer (score 4):

Psychologically speaking, red means caution, stop, or no, and green means good, healthy, or go.
See: http://www.psychologicalscience.org/index.php/news/releases/stop-on-red-a-monkey-study-suggests-that-the-effects-of-color-lie-deep-in-evolution.html
and:  http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/people-places-and-things/201002/positive-design-color

Comment: Great with reference! +1